# Makefile (erlang.mk) can't find file that exists

Tags: bash, makefile, grep, erlang

I am trying to build a project who's Makefile imports an erlang.mk, that imports other Makefiles and erlang.mks.

In one erlang.mk I have a `grep` call inside a conditional in a recipe that looks like this

```
if grep ^$$dep$$ $(ERLANG_MK_TMP)/deps.log; then \
```

and that's printing

```
grep: /home/forrealthough/code/rabbitmq-consistent-hash/.erlang.mk/deps.log: No such file or directory
```

with a return code of 2. If I put this line just before

```
if [ ! -f $$ERLANG_MK_TMP/deps.log ]; then echo "File not found!"; fi;\
```

I get a "File not found!".

The file does exist, I can `cat` it from the same directory and run the same `if` line without getting a "File not found!". Its permissions are `-rw-rw-r--` and I get the same error running `make` with or without `sudo`.

Why can't my script find this file?

EDIT: I was asked to alter my `if` test, so here is the relevant section of my script (this is inside a recipe):

```
echo file: $(ERLANG_MK_TMP)/deps.log;\
if [ ! -f $(ERLANG_MK_TMP)/deps.log ]; then echo "File not found!"; fi;\
if grep ^$$dep$$ $(ERLANG_MK_TMP)/deps.log; then \
```

and they print

```
file: /home/forrealthough/rabbitmq-consistent-hash/.erlang.mk/deps.log
File not found!
grep: /home/forrealthough/rabbitmq-consistent-hash/.erlang.mk/deps.log: No such file or directory
make: *** [erlang.mk:4322: deps] Error 2
```

Again, the file does exist. `grep` returns status code=2, which I checked echoing `$$?`, and it runs the `else` part of the conditional.

EDIT 2: If I put a `ls $(ERLANG_MK_TMP);\` along those other tests it lists every file inside that directory, except deps.log, which, again, is there. This fits other tests I did where I tried to access different files from this script, and deps.log is the only one that couldn't be found.

I have this same script inside this same project being built as a module of a different project (Another Makefile that imports another erlang.mk that tries to build the Makefile of the project I'm working on). There the script can find the file in question, and it runs normally.

Comment: I think you messed up some syntax. 1) `$(ERLANG_MK_TMP)` this will call a command named `ERLANG_MK_TMP` which looks fine according the name, but not according to all uppercase name, I suppose it is a variable, so try ${ERLANG_MK_TMP} or just `$ERLANG_MK_TMP` . 2) you need to escape $$ in grep. try `echo ^$$dep$$` I don't think you wanted this. you also wrote `$$ERLANG_MK_TMP` which is also wrong

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that this part is a recipe inside a Makefile (erlang.mk). I edited my question to explain this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(ERLANG_MK_TMP)` is a make variable.  `$$ERLANG_MK_TMP` is an (escaped) shell variable.  The latter will only have a value if you export the former, it won't have any value if you just assign a make variable in the makefile without exporting it.

Why did you use two different formats here?  Why not use:

```
if [ ! -f $(ERLANG_MK_TMP)/deps.log ]; then ...
```

?

Comment: For no particular reason, I'm not familiar with Make syntax and I just copied from the internet. But it keeps giving the "File not found" output, and if I change it to a different existing file it stops.

Comment: You mean even after you made the change I recommended above, it still gives the error?  If so please cut and paste exactly the command printed by make and the error output you get (edit your question to add this, not in a comment).  If you want to understand makefiles I urge you to use the GNU make manual, not random examples on the internet: there are a LOT of bad makefiles out there.  https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Introduction.html

Comment: Yes, even after I made the change you recommended. I edited the original post with the info you requested. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: There's no question that when that makefile recipe runs, that file doesn't exist.  I don't know what to tell you: nothing in your question gives a hint as to how or why that is.  Both the if-statement and grep agree that it's not there.  Are you absolutely sure that the file exists before you run make?  Please cut and paste the pathname that make is printing into your `ls` command so you're sure you aren't typing a different pathname than your recipe is using.  If it's there before you type make, then some other recipe in your makefile must be deleting it before this one runs.

Comment: I haven't considered that, but yes, I'm now 100% sure the file is deleted and recreated at a different point. Thanks for making me see this. The project wasn't written by me, so I'm not sure how it works.